# viewing frames of animation

Tags: animation

I have a simple query, (I hope). I have a few frames of a walking figure which I can animate, but I need to access the frames so I can print and trace them for hand drawn work. Problem is, after I animate them, where do they go???

Answer (score 1):

With the default key bindings, `F12` will render a frame, and `F11` will toggle the render view on and off.  The rendered result is shown in the "UV Image Editor" panel.  In that view, select from the menus `Image -> Save As Image` to save the one frame.

If you have more than just one or two frames, this will quickly get tedious.  Go into Scene settings, set up an output folder, and you can render a stack of separate frame images in one go.